# Remove Items from Embedded List<object> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, class

All, I have the following class structure

```
public class Foo : IComparable<Foo> 
{
    public List<Bar> Bars;
}

public class Bar : IComparable<Bar> 
{
    public List<Con> Cons;
}

public class Con : IComparable<Con>
{
    ...
}
```

I know how to remove object from a list

```
authorsList.RemoveAll(x => x.FirstName == "Bob");
```

But how, for my class above, do I remove a `List<Con>` called `badConList`, from my base object `Foo`? Explicitly, the class hierarchy is populated like

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bars = new List<Bar>() { /* Some Bar list */ };
foreach (Bar bar in foo.Bars)
    bar.Cons = new List<Con>() { /* Some Con list */ };

// Now a bad Con list.
List<Con> badCons = new List() { /* Some bad Con list */ };
```

How do I remove the `badCons` from `foo` for each `Bar` using LINQ?

Thanks for your time.

*Ps. LINQ may not be the quickest method here; a simple loop might be (which is what LINQ will be doing under the hood anyway). Can you comment on this also?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can use `RemoveAll`:

```
bar.Cons.RemoveAll(x => badCons.Contains(x));
```

An alternate solution would be to use a loop:

```
foreach(var badCon in badCons)
    bar.Cons.Remove(badCon);
```

Both versions loop one of the lists multiple times:

1. The first version loops `badCons` N times with N being `bar.Cons.Count()`.
2. The second version loops `bar.Cons` N times with N being `badCons.Count()`.

If one of the two lists is magnitudes larger than the other, it is a good idea to choose the version that loops the large list only once, otherwise use the version that is simpler to understand to you and the readers of your codebase.

Comment: or for a one liner on the second one, you can do `badCons.ForEach(b => bar.Cons.Remove(b))` :)

Comment: @mattytommo: I don't like that method and therefore avoid it. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for more info.

Comment: The problem I have is that there is a list of `Bar`s I have to itterate as well. How can I incorporate that in the LINQ version of the above? I hope this is clear... Thanks for your time Daniel.

Comment: Use the List<T>.ForEach method explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx

Comment: @Killercam: Simply put a `foreach(var bar in foo.Bars)` around both versions.

Comment: @PetkoPetkov: Please see the link in my comment to mattytommo why I don't use this method.

Comment: Is there no way to perform the out itteration using LINQ. I suppose I am just interested in how this is achieved using Fluent syntax? Again, thanks.

Comment: Don't worry Daniel, I don't like it either :). I was merely suggesting an alternative one liner for the second one :). That blog post from Eric I read a while back and that's why I decided against them.

Comment: @Killercam: You can use the `ForEach` method as others suggested, but I see no benefit. In fact, I think it hurts readability: `bars.ForEach(bar => bar.RemoveAll(x => badCons.Contains(x)))` or `badCons.ForEach(x => bars.ForEach(bar => bar.Cons.Remove(x)))`